# How to call Turkish to Ascii character conversion?

Tags: terminology, turkish

When writing software in some cases we are not allowed to use Turkish characters so we use U, G, S, I, i, O, C characters instead of Ü, Ğ, Ş, İ, ı, Ö and Ç since some computer systems might not support Turkish character set. So in our software we use simple mapper to replace those characters with equivalent one. My question is how would you call this process? Transcription, transliteration or something else?

Comment: Transliteration seems to be the good word.

Comment: Confusingly, *transliteration* is used for both directions.  There is also *diacritic removal/restoration* but `ı` has no diacritic.  Usually the function is just called *toASCII()*, but many of them are not well-implemented, because ideally they should take language as a parameter, so that tr *güzel* will be *guzel* but de *München* will be *Muenchen*.

Comment: I think we should broaden this question to include most languages written in the Latin alphabet with non-ASCII characters, like Spanish, French and German, leaving aside the question of whether English has any.

Comment: I really do not see the point of replacing the perfectly adequate Turkish orthography with one that is completely inadequate for the language, What is actually the point of ASCII?

Comment: @fdb Mostly for old systems and libraries that can't deal with Unicode. Which should really have been eradicated by now, but are still all over the place and have to be dealt with. (For one example, most US government applications only allow ASCII characters, so names and words in other languages have to be transliterated.)

Comment: @fdb ASCIIifing a Latin alphabet language is nothing.  Utility and emergency SMSes sent by most telecoms use ASCII even in countries where the language is not in the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

In general usage, *transcription* involves going from the sounds of a language to written symbols, and *transliteration* involves going from one set of written symbols to another.

Since you're starting with written symbols (in Unicode) and converting them to other written symbols (in ASCII), this would be transliteration. If you want to be more specific, call it "ASCII transliteration", or "lossy transliteration" (since it removes distinctions like `i` versus `ı` that the original writing preserved).